# Configure NServicebus in Asp.net Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, nservicebus, .net-5

I am using the [NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/extensions-hosting) extension to configure NServicebus

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseNServiceBus(c =>
            {
                var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("nsb.medusa");
                endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>().ConnectionString("How do I access app settings?");
                endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();
                return endpointConfiguration;
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to get an instance of IConfiguration from a IHostBuilder. I need IConfiguration so I can get the connection string to RabbitMQ.

Also can this be moved to the startup class?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has some excellent [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0). After reading it I just added two lines of code and I can now access the configuration.

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseNServiceBus(c =>
            {
                var configuration = c.Configuration; /* New */
                var cnnStr = configuration.GetSection("mq:connection").Value;  /* New */
                var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("nsb.medusa");
                endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>().ConnectionString(cnnStr);
                endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();
                return endpointConfiguration;
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```